# Discord.js how to use bot mention and a set prefix as prefixes

Tags: discord, discord.js, prefix, mention

I want to make it so that if I do `[prefix] [command]` it will give the same effect as `[mention bot] [command]` but the way I create commands and args makes that difficult:

The prefix is stored as `var prefix = '!3';`

And this is how I create commands:

```js
bot.on('message', msg => {

    if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix) || msg.author.bot)
        return;

  //the first message after '!13 '
        //!
    let args = msg.content.toLowerCase().substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
                           //^
          //any capitalisation is allowed (ping,Ping,pIng etc.)

switch(args[1]) {
      case 'ping': //if user inputs '!3 ping'
            msg.channel.send('Pong!') //send a message to the channel 'Pong!'
}//switch (command) ends here
};//event listener ends here
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have a list of predefined prefixes and loop over that to determine if the msg has a prefix from that list.

```
let prefixList = ['!31 ', '!asdf ', `<@${bot.user.id}> `, `<@!${bot.user.id}> `]

function hasPrefix(str) {
    for(let pre of prefixList)
        if(str.startsWith(pre))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

`<@${bot.user.id}>` , `<@!${bot.user.id}>`  will set up bot mention as a prefix.

Comment: Good answer :D 
Helped me out, too

Comment: I have to add that I don't recommend using bot mention as the main prefix for commands because apparently Discord creates a role by the same name as your bot. It is easy for users to accidentally mention the role instead of the bot. The code I provided above doesn't include role mention as a prefix.

Comment: This is an error I got
```
['!3', '<@${bot.user.id}> ', '<@!${bot.user.id}> ']
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
```

Comment: I recommend you put that part of the code either inside bot.on('message', ...) or bot.on('read', ...)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are running on an older version of Discord.js cause if you are using v13 `message` is depricated and should be `messageCreate` but this is what I used when I wasn't using slash commands.

```js
const escapeRegex = str => str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')
const prefix = '!'

bot.on('message', async msg => {
    const prefixRegex = new RegExp(`^(<@!?${bot.user.id}>|${escapeRegex(prefix)})\\s*`)
    if (!prefixRegex.test(message.content)) return
    // checks for bot mention or prefix

    const [, matchedPrefix] = message.content.match(prefixRegex)
    const args = message.content.slice(matchedPrefix.length).trim().split(/ +/)
    // removes prefix or bot mention

    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()
    // gets command from next arg

    if (command === 'ping') {
        msg.channel.send('Pong!')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the shorter version of `secretlyrice's` answer:

```
const startsWithPrefix = (command) => 
['!prefix1 ', '!prefix2', <@botId>, <@!botId>].some(p => command.startsWith(p))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Nice code, but change it 1 to 0

```js
switch(args[0]) {
      case 'ping': //if user inputs '!3 ping'
            msg.channel.send('Pong!') //send a message to the channel 'Pong!'
}
```